# Redefining methods of inherited class within Python package

Tags: python, module

Say I have a Python package structured as such:

```
/summary
    __init__.py
    summary.py
    /temperature
        __init__.py
        temperature.py
```

Where the class TempSummary (defined in temperature.py) inherits from the base class, Summary (defined in summary.py), defined, respectively, as:

```
class TempSummary(Summary):
    def __init__(self, f):
        bar(f)

class Summary:
    def __init__(self, f):
        foo(f)
```

Would one copy over the contents of summary.py to /temperature and modify the class's methods there, in the copied file, or is it more Pythonic to inherit to TempSummary and then start modifying the methods' behavior?

Answer (score 0):

copying code violates [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (Dont repeat yourself).  It becomes a nightmare to maintain 2 sets of code in parrallel.

It is the OOP approach to sublcass and override the methods of your choice to create custom functionality.

If you are extending some `Summary` methods remember to [call the parent method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super)!